# How to group by and get 1 max value and 2 max value rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Raw Data...

| RefNo | rest1 | Pair | rest2 | rest3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | E | 55 | 7 |
| B | 22 | F | 66 | 6 |
| C | 33 | G | 77 | 5 |
| C | 33 | H | 88 | 4 |
| D | 44 | I | 99 | 3 |
| D | 44 | J | 111 | 2 |
| D | 44 | K | 222 | 1 |

1. Groupby(RefNo) and get MaxValue(rest2) row...

| RefNo | rest1 | Pair | rest2 | rest3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | E | 55 | 7 |
| B | 22 | F | 66 | 6 |
| C | 33 | H | 88 | 4 |
| D | 44 | K | 222 | 1 |

2. Groupby(RefNo) and get 2 MaxValue(rest2) rows...

| RefNo | rest1 | Pair | rest2 | rest3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | E | 55 | 7 |
| B | 22 | F | 66 | 6 |
| C | 33 | H | 88 | 4 |
| C | 33 | G | 77 | 5 |
| D | 44 | K | 222 | 1 |
| D | 44 | J | 111 | 2 |

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
n = 2

out = df[df.groupby('RefNo')['rest2'].rank('dense').le(n)]
```

Output:

```
  RefNo  rest1 Pair  rest2  rest3
0     A     11    E     55      7
1     B     22    F     66      6
2     C     33    G     77      5
3     C     33    H     88      4
4     D     44    I     99      3
5     D     44    J    111      2
```

Intermediates:

```
  RefNo  rest1 Pair  rest2  rest3  rank   mask
0     A     11    E     55      7   1.0   True
1     B     22    F     66      6   1.0   True
2     C     33    G     77      5   1.0   True
3     C     33    H     88      4   2.0   True
4     D     44    I     99      3   1.0   True
5     D     44    J    111      2   2.0   True
6     D     44    K    222      1   3.0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = 2
df.sort_values('rest2',ascending=False).groupby('RefNo').head(n).sort_index()
```

or

```
df.loc[df.groupby('RefNo')['rest2'].nlargest(n).droplevel(0).index]
```

Output:

```
  RefNo  rest1 Pair  rest2  rest3
0     A     11    E     55      7
1     B     22    F     66      6
3     C     33    H     88      4
2     C     33    G     77      5
6     D     44    K    222      1
5     D     44    J    111      2
```